# Fluent UI Modal dialog resizing and not taking whole screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have Fluent UI modal dialog that I am showing in my site very similar to below example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-boyd-m5rw2k?file=/example.tsx

EDIT: The code in codesandbox.io is the same as the one below:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTrigger,
  DialogSurface,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogBody,
  DialogContent,
  DialogActions,
  Button,
  makeStyles,
  shorthands
} from "@fluentui/react-components";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dialog: {
    maxWidth: "fit-content",
    width: "52.875rem",
    ...shorthands.borderRadius("1rem")
  },

  title: {
    paddingBottom: "1rem"
  },

  dialogContent: {
    maxHeight: "50rem",
    paddingRight: "2.5rem"
  }
});

export const ScrollingLongContent = () => {
  const styles = useStyles();

  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogTrigger disableButtonEnhancement>
        <Button>Open dialog</Button>
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogSurface className={styles.dialog}>
        <DialogBody>
          <DialogTitle className={styles.title}>Dialog title</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent className={styles.dialogContent}>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisl
              pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Leo vel fringilla est
              ullamcorper. Eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
              adipiscing elit. In mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit
              gravida. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Dolor
              sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Facilisi morbi tempus
              iaculis urna id volutpat. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet
              suspendisse. Nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in. A
              iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo. Proin nibh nisl
              condimentum id. In hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum
              rhoncus est. Non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque.
              Enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor.
              Nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer.
              Ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Leo in vitae
              turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed.
            </p>
            <p>
              Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Venenatis urna cursus
              eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Neque aliquam vestibulum
              morbi blandit. Porttitor eget dolor morbi non. Nisi quis eleifend
              quam adipiscing vitae. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a
              scelerisque purus semper. Interdum varius sit amet mattis
              vulputate enim nulla aliquet. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet
              tellus cras. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis
              egestas. Amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim.
              Neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Arcu cursus euismod
              quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Ultrices eros in
              cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui. Nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus
              urna neque viverra justo. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo
              sed egestas. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper.
              Ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. Faucibus ornare suspendisse sed
              nisi lacus sed. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum
              arcu vitae elementum. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis
              imperdiet.
            </p>
            <p>
              Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim. Amet
              cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Eget aliquet nibh praesent
              tristique magna sit. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo.
              Pharetra massa massa ultricies mi. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit
              amet. Pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed.
              Pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum.
              Consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
              tellus in metus vulputate. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a
              erat. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus.
              Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Neque laoreet
              suspendisse interdum consectetur. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut
              placerat orci. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum
              suspendisse. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices
              dui. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet.
            </p>
            <p>
              At risus viverra adipiscing at. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor
              sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vel risus commodo
              viverra maecenas. Sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet
              sed euismod. Turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere.
              Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor
              aliquam. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam purus
              sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla. Scelerisque
              fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Egestas maecenas
              pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. A diam sollicitudin
              tempor id eu nisl nunc. Lectus sit amet est placerat.
            </p>
            <p>
              Mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare
              massa eget. At tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id
              nibh. Dui faucibus in ornare quam. Tincidunt id aliquet risus
              feugiat in ante metus dictum. Adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet
              dui. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam
              sit amet nisl. Hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor
              sit amet. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque
              adipiscing. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit
              amet commodo nulla. Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus.
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisl
              pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Leo vel fringilla est
              ullamcorper. Eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
              adipiscing elit. In mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit
              gravida. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Dolor
              sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Facilisi morbi tempus
              iaculis urna id volutpat. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet
              suspendisse. Nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in. A
              iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo. Proin nibh nisl
              condimentum id. In hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum
              rhoncus est. Non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque.
              Enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor.
              Nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer.
              Ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Leo in vitae
              turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed.
            </p>
            <p>
              Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Venenatis urna cursus
              eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Neque aliquam vestibulum
              morbi blandit. Porttitor eget dolor morbi non. Nisi quis eleifend
              quam adipiscing vitae. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a
              scelerisque purus semper. Interdum varius sit amet mattis
              vulputate enim nulla aliquet. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet
              tellus cras. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis
              egestas. Amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim.
              Neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Arcu cursus euismod
              quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Ultrices eros in
              cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui. Nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus
              urna neque viverra justo. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo
              sed egestas. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper.
              Ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. Faucibus ornare suspendisse sed
              nisi lacus sed. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum
              arcu vitae elementum. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis
              imperdiet.
            </p>
            <p>
              Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim. Amet
              cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Eget aliquet nibh praesent
              tristique magna sit. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo.
              Pharetra massa massa ultricies mi. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit
              amet. Pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed.
              Pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum.
              Consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
              tellus in metus vulputate. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a
              erat. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus.
              Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Neque laoreet
              suspendisse interdum consectetur. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut
              placerat orci. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum
              suspendisse. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices
              dui. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet.
            </p>
            <p>
              At risus viverra adipiscing at. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor
              sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vel risus commodo
              viverra maecenas. Sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet
              sed euismod. Turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere.
              Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor
              aliquam. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam purus
              sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla. Scelerisque
              fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Egestas maecenas
              pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. A diam sollicitudin
              tempor id eu nisl nunc. Lectus sit amet est placerat.
            </p>
            <p>
              Mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare
              massa eget. At tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id
              nibh. Dui faucibus in ornare quam. Tincidunt id aliquet risus
              feugiat in ante metus dictum. Adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet
              dui. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam
              sit amet nisl. Hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor
              sit amet. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque
              adipiscing. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit
              amet commodo nulla. Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus.
            </p>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <DialogTrigger disableButtonEnhancement>
              <Button appearance="secondary">Close</Button>
            </DialogTrigger>
            <Button appearance="primary">Do Something</Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </DialogBody>
      </DialogSurface>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

The dialog renders well but it takes the whole screen when I zoom in with my browser or I use a screen with a lower resolution. Is there a way I can maintain a padding between the modal dialog and the overall host, so it never goes to the entire screen?

This is how it looks when it looks good:
[image]

And this is how it looks when I zoom in. It just takes the whole screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any one `margin` to the dialog.
Also some more css properties to make it look normal, because actually the code in this component is pretty dirty... Here's what you need to add:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dialog: {
    '--margin': "1rem",
    maxWidth: "calc(100% - var(--margin))",
    maxHeight: "calc(100% - var(--margin))",
    //...
  },
  //...
  dialogBody: {
    minHeight: 0,
  },
  dialogActions: {
    marginTop: "1rem"
  }
});
```

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-clarke-ym2m8y)

Comment: Worked like a charm! EDIT:For some reason the bounty button doesn't work to me right now but I will try that out at night.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS [vw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length?#vw) property.

> 1vw is 1% of the viewport width. For example, if the viewport width is 800px, then a value of 50vw on a property will be 400px. ([link to source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length?#vw))

You can then combine that with `@media (max-width: ...` as you probably need less horizontal padding on mobile devices

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dialog: {
    maxWidth: "fit-content",
    width: "70vw",
    '@media (max-width: 780px)': { // adjust width to your needs
      width: '90vw',
      backgroundColor: 'red'       // red color only to show when it changes
    },
    ...shorthands.borderRadius("1rem")
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually that's really easy to achieve, you just have to take into account the different screen sizes. Here are the updated styles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dialog: {
    maxWidth: "fit-content",
    width: "80vw",
    ...shorthands.borderRadius("1rem"),
    "@media(min-width: 1200px)": {
      // for screens larger than 1200px
      width: "52.875rem" // use a fixed width
    }
  },

  title: {
    paddingBottom: "1rem"
  },

  dialogContent: {
    // reduce a little the size of the content height for better sizing
    maxHeight: "35rem",
    paddingRight: "2.5rem"
  }
});
```

Here is a fully working sandbox: https://rcpklh.csb.app/

Just play with the numbers until you get your perfect design :)

[image]
[image]